# operator<< overloading, namespaces, and templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Here is a piece of code, overloading the << operator :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace MyNamespace
{
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    const int a = 5;
    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<U>& obj); 
};
}

template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyNamespace::MyClass<U>& obj)
{
    return cout << obj.a;
}

int main()
{
    MyNamespace::MyClass<int> foo;
    cout << foo;

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get an 'ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'.

I don't understand why...

Comment: Because there is a `MyNamespace::operator<<` and a `operator<<`

Answer (score 2):

You have a

```
std::ostream& MyNamespace::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<U>& obj);
```

declared in your class as `friend` and a

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyNamespace::MyClass<U>& obj)
```

in the global namespace. To tell C++ that the second one, the global one, is your friend function and not the one in your namespace, append a `::` to the name:

```
std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass<U>& obj);
```

*Or better yet, move the function to your own namespace.*

Comment: Better to move `operator <<` in the same `namespace` than `MyClass` BTW.

Comment: The problem is that the member a is actually in my code a vector. I wrote a serializer for vectors, but is not in MyNamespace. It seems that causes troubles if I put the << function for MyClass in this namespace.
The compiler try to convert the vector to a stream (??).
No problem if I code the first proposed solution.